# Tricky getting average for price when summing extended and qty

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

The data we display is summarized by order type. Data looks: where ABCDE is the sum of one or more rows with same item #.

```
Item  Order Type    QTY  PRICE    EXT. PRICE
ABCDE   INT         10            $100
```

I am not displaying price because this row is a summary of several in time frame selected. Price on these items changes in time or for customer.

So What I can do is give an average price.

I have 2 formulas but the result is not correct. all result is same number 91,979.00

1. formula 'new avg'  sum({DATA_WHSV3.ITEM_PRC$}) / count({DATA_WHSV3.ITEM_PRC$})
2. then  If {@new avg} > 0 then

   ```
     sum({DATA_WHSV3.ITEM_PRC$})/{@new avg}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Running Total Field to do the average for you. So say your report is grouped by Item# you would create a new Running Total Field.

**Running Total Name:** RTotal0 (can be anything, this is just the default)
**Field to Summarize:** `{DATA_WHSV3.ITEM_PRC$}`
**Type of Summary:** average
**Evaluate:** For each record
**Reset:** On change of group: Group #1: DATA_WHSV3.ITEM_NUMBER

Then you can drop the `{#RTotal0}` into the group footer along with the other details for that item number and it should be the correct average.